# How to a Add text to Range

Tags: excel, vba

What I have:

`Range("A" & i+1).value=Range("B" & i).value`

What I Need:

`"'" & Range("A" & i+1).value=Range("B" & i).value`

The output I Need:

`'1234`

How do I add that type of text using VBA I'm trying to implement with other functions but it is giving me an error

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the order mixed up:

`Range("A" & i+1).value = "'" & Range("B" & i).value`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format given cell as a text, then this is a working solution:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1") = 1234
End Sub
```